# Is Dstream map and Dstream transform map the same in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stream, dstream

Are the following two the same?

```
val dstream = stream.window(Seconds(60), Seconds(1))
val x = dstream.map(x => ...)
```

and

```
val dstream = stream.window(Seconds(60), Seconds(1))
val x = dstream.transform(rdd => rdd.map(x => ...))
```

Comment: Exact duplicate in my opinion, may be helpful :)

Comment: Just tell if the above two are same or not. The question you have linked, still does not make this thing clear. From what I understand, these two will give the same output.

Answer (score 1):

> map(func) Return a new DStream by passing each element of the source
>   DStream through a function func.

and

> transform(func)   Return a new DStream by applying a RDD-to-RDD function
>   to every RDD of the source DStream. This can be used to do arbitrary
>   RDD operations on the DStream.

in short transform function in Spark streaming we can use for any of Apache Spark's transformations on the underlying RDDs for the stream. map is used for an element to element transform.

> Essentially, map works on the elements of the DStream and transform
>   allows you to work with the RDDs of the DStream(map works on each rows transform works on each rdd).

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams

**map Example**

```
val clicks: DStream[...] = ...
val mappedClicks: ... = clicks.map(...)
```

**transform Example**

```
transform(transformFunc: RDD[T] => RDD[U]): DStream[U]
transform(transformFunc: (RDD[T], Time) => RDD[U]): DStream[U]
```

Comment: That didn't answer my question. In this case, will the output be the same or not, and if not, why?

Comment: You can get same result using transform instead of map